# How to use index for simple time range join?

Tags: postgresql, index, execution-plan, performance, range-types, postgresql-performance

I have a large (~ 100 million rows) timeseries table `t_16` in **Postgres 11.5**  where the primary key is a field `abs_date_time` of type `timestamp`.

This is a follow up of this question:

- [Why does a CTE cause a full table scan?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/254254/why-does-a-cte-cause-a-full-table-scan)

Initially I thought it was related to a CTE. But *this* query is slow, even without CTE.

**How** can I make the following query **use the primary key index**, to avoid a full table scan?

#### tsrange

This query takes **~20sec** on my dev PC:

```
SELECT t_16_gen.*
FROM t_16_gen,
     (VALUES (tsrange('["2019-11-26 12:00:00","2019-11-26 12:00:15")'))
           , (tsrange('["2019-11-26 13:00:00","2019-11-26 13:00:15")'))) as ranges (time_range)
WHERE (abs_date_time >= LOWER(ranges.time_range)
    AND abs_date_time <  UPPER(ranges.time_range));
```

Explain plan:

```
Gather  (cost=1000.00..6185287.15 rows=20571433 width=80)
  Workers Planned: 2
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..4127143.85 rows=8571430 width=80)
        Join Filter: ((t_16_gen.abs_date_time >= lower("*VALUES*".column1)) AND (t_16_gen.abs_date_time < upper("*VALUES*".column1)))
        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on t_16_gen  (cost=0.00..1620000.38 rows=38571438 width=80)
        ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.03 rows=2 width=32)
```

In production the set of tsranges comes from a UDF - but there will always be only a few ranges (<200) and each range will have less than 1500 rows and the ranges will not overlap.

#### Simple timestamps instead of `tsrange`

Whenwe use timestamps directly (i.e. not using tsrange, `LOWER()` and `UPPER()`), the query is already faster. This query takes **~7sec** on my dev PC:

```
SELECT t_16_gen.*
FROM t_16_gen,
     (VALUES ('2019-11-26 12:00:00'::timestamp,'2019-11-26 12:00:15'::timestamp)
           , ('2019-11-26 13:00:00','2019-11-26 13:00:15')) as ranges (start_incl, end_excl)
WHERE (abs_date_time >= ranges.start_incl
    AND abs_date_time <  ranges.end_excl);
```

Explain plan:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..5400001.28 rows=20571433 width=80)
  Join Filter: ((t_16_gen.abs_date_time >= "*VALUES*".column1) AND (t_16_gen.abs_date_time < "*VALUES*".column2))
  ->  Seq Scan on t_16_gen  (cost=0.00..2160000.50 rows=92571450 width=80)
  ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..0.04 rows=2 width=16)
        ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.03 rows=2 width=16)
```

#### `OR` conditions = FAST

When I rewrite the query to use **OR** conditions it is fast. This query takes **~200ms** on my dev PC:

```
SELECT t_16_gen.*
FROM t_16_gen
WHERE (abs_date_time >= '2019-11-26 12:00:00' AND abs_date_time < '2019-11-26 12:00:15')
   OR (abs_date_time >= '2019-11-26 13:00:00' AND abs_date_time < '2019-11-26 13:00:15');
```

Explain plan:

```
Gather  (cost=13326.98..1533350.92 rows=923400 width=80)
  Workers Planned: 2
  ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on t_16_gen  (cost=12326.98..1440010.92 rows=384750 width=80)
        Recheck Cond: (((abs_date_time >= '2019-11-26 12:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (abs_date_time < '2019-11-26 12:00:15'::timestamp without time zone)) OR ((abs_date_time >= '2019-11-26 13:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (abs_date_time < '2019-11-26 13:00:15'::timestamp without time zone)))
        ->  BitmapOr  (cost=12326.98..12326.98 rows=925714 width=0)
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on t_16_pkey  (cost=0.00..5932.64 rows=462857 width=0)
                    Index Cond: ((abs_date_time >= '2019-11-26 12:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (abs_date_time < '2019-11-26 12:00:15'::timestamp without time zone))
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on t_16_pkey  (cost=0.00..5932.64 rows=462857 width=0)
                    Index Cond: ((abs_date_time >= '2019-11-26 13:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (abs_date_time < '2019-11-26 13:00:15'::timestamp without time zone))
```

#### `UNION` = FAST

When I rewrite the query to use **UNION** conditions it is also fast. This query takes **~220ms** on my dev PC:

```
SELECT t_16_gen.*
FROM t_16_gen
WHERE (abs_date_time >= '2019-11-26 12:00:00' AND abs_date_time < '2019-11-26 12:00:15')
UNION
SELECT t_16_gen.*
FROM t_16_gen
WHERE (abs_date_time >= '2019-11-26 13:00:00' AND abs_date_time < '2019-11-26 13:00:15');
```

Explain plan:

```
Unique  (cost=1032439.64..1069468.20 rows=925714 width=80)
  ->  Sort  (cost=1032439.64..1034753.93 rows=925714 width=80)
"        Sort Key: t_16_gen.abs_date_time, t_16_gen.c_422, t_16_gen.c_423, t_16_gen.c_424, t_16_gen.c_425, t_16_gen.c_426, t_16_gen.c_427, t_16_gen.c_428, t_16_gen.c_429, t_16_gen.c_430, t_16_gen.c_431, t_16_gen.c_432, t_16_gen.c_433, t_16_gen.c_434, t_16_gen.c_435"
        ->  Append  (cost=0.57..892513.13 rows=925714 width=80)
              ->  Index Scan using t_16_pkey on t_16_gen  (cost=0.57..439313.71 rows=462857 width=80)
                    Index Cond: ((abs_date_time >= '2019-11-26 12:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (abs_date_time < '2019-11-26 12:00:15'::timestamp without time zone))
              ->  Index Scan using t_16_pkey on t_16_gen t_16_gen_1  (cost=0.57..439313.71 rows=462857 width=80)
                    Index Cond: ((abs_date_time >= '2019-11-26 13:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (abs_date_time < '2019-11-26 13:00:15'::timestamp without time zone))
```

#### Reproducing the issue

To reproduce the issue, I can create a new table and fill it with dummy data. Then restart the database before each test, so that the data is not cached.
Note: the insert query may run for several minutes!

```
create table if not exists t_16_gen (
    abs_date_time timestamp constraint t_16_pkey primary key,
    c_422 bigint,
    c_423 bigint,
    c_424 real,
    c_425 real,
    c_426 real,
    c_427 real,
    c_428 real,
    c_429 real,
    c_430 bigint,
    c_431 real,
    c_432 real,
    c_433 real,
    c_434 bigint,
    c_435 real
);

INSERT INTO t_16_gen
SELECT ts, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14
FROM (SELECT generate_series('2019-11-26'::timestamp, '2019-11-27', '1 millisecond') as ts) as gs;
```

Comment: Are ranges always 10 minutes long?

Comment: @SQLRaptor unfortunately not: the start/ends can be arbitrary

Comment: When I implement my own t_16, it uses the index as expected.  Please include a full test case, showing us the table creation, population, index creation, etc. (and which still reproduces the issue).

Comment: 1. In that case, be sure to check 'fast' vs 'slow' for longer ranges as well... what works well for 10 minutes might prove to be a catastrophe for 10 days. 2. Why do you have 2 identical range rows in the VALUES clause? Why do you cross join the filter values instead of parameters? Did you try without the OR, just - `SELECT t_16.*
FROM t_16
WHERE (abs_date_time >= '2019-11-26 12:00:00' AND abs_date_time < '2019-11-26 12:10:00')`?

Comment: .. and please start by disclosing the Postgres version in use. Always.

Comment: @SQLRaptor Thanks for the good points. _2._ was by accident, I've updated the queries. _"Why do you cross join the filter values instead of parameters?"_: because this query is part of a larger query in production: so the time-ranges are not a direct input from the application, but an output from a former UDF

Comment: @jjanes Good point. I've added the statementes to create a similar table and add dummy data.

Comment: With version 11, it only does the seq scan if t_16_gen has never been vacuum analyzed.  Once it has been analyzed (and so knows that the there is a strong correlation between the table order and the primary key order) then it strongly prefers the plan you want.

Comment: Your added demo table does not completely fit the rest of the info. 10 min intervals would capture 600,000 rows, while you stated that `each duration is guaranteed to have less than 1500 rows`.

Comment: You are right. I've added the test table in an update and forgot to change the related queries. Now, I've updated all the queries and explain plans in the question to be consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last (fast) query has two identical `WHERE` conditions, which Postgres is able to identify and fold to ***one***. Hence the simpler plan with just a single index condition.

It gets more expensive with multiple *different* conditions. But Postgres still keeps operating based on estimates for actual input values. Try with one or more  large intervals in the `WHERE` clause including most or all of the table and you will see a sequential scan instead.

That's different in principle for your first two queries based on a `VALUES` expression. There, Postgres forks two cases:

- For ***one*** input row Postgres looks at actual values and produces the same plan as for your third query with a single `WHERE` condition, with estimates based on actual input values. You get index / bitmap index / sequential scan accordingly.
- For ***more than one*** input row, Postgres stops looking at individual values, and prepares a query plan based on ***generic*** estimates and the actual number of input rows. You can provide a `VALUES` expression with 5 rows resulting in no result at all or 5 rows returning the whole table, it will be the same query plan.

Tested in Postgres 11.

Also be aware that joining to a set (the `VALUES` expression) is **logically different** from adding multiple `OR`'ed range predicates. Rows matching multiple time ranges in the set are returned multiple times, while the second form only ever returns a single instance, even if that matches multiple predicates.

So the second form with many `OR`'s naturally favors bitmap index scans, which folds multiple hits into one automatically. Postgres has no idea that your conditions never overlap. (Or will they?? Then you have a bigger problem.) If data in your table is physically sorted by time (matching your PK column `abs_date_time`), then this should still work in your favor *by accident*.

**But** since your rows are rather wide (fewer tuples per page), and if you have many time ranges (up to 200?), unduly favoring bitmap index scans might be a disadvantage after all and simple index scans might be faster.

#### Solution

**`UNION ALL`** should be **superior** for you!

```
SELECT * FROM s_28.t_16 WHERE abs_date_time >= '2019-11-26 12:00:00' AND abs_date_time < '2019-11-26 12:10:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM s_28.t_16 WHERE abs_date_time >= '2019-11-26 13:00:00' AND abs_date_time < '2019-11-26 13:10:00'
-- add (many) more
;
```

First of all, it's the best match for the logic at work here. Chances are much better that future versions of Postgres will keep using good query plans.

This way, Postgres uses estimates based on actual input for each `SELECT` - and given your specs (all ranges are tiny) the query should *never* degrade to sequential scans, as long as your table statistics are not completely misleading.

And index scans are not at an (unfair) disadvantage against bitmap index scans any more.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation.So in my case, I think I should split the query in 2 parts: First calculate the time ranges, then - in app-code - build a new query with multiple `OR` conditions in the `WHERE` clause. We should typically have less than 10 conditions (200 in the worst case). And all durations will ever only span a small fraction of the table (each duration is guaranteed to have less than 1500 rows).

Comment: @TmTron: I assume you are aware that both queries return different results for overlapping input ranges. Thinking of it some more, a better solution comes to mind. Consider the update.

Comment: The rnage do not overlap. I forgot to mention that.